# Is it a good practice declaring a integer in a method that is going to be called in a loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my code, I have a method that I will require declaring a method to count, can I declare the variable inside the method?

```
bool CheckArrays(int arrArg1[5][9], vector <int> arrArg2)
{
    int idk;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        CheckArrays(X, X2);
    }
}
```

as you can see everytime he calls the function `CheckArrays(X,X2)` in the function `CheckArrays` he declares `int idk`, so is it the best practice of doing it?

Will it waste memory by declaring it everytime?(in a bigger method as example).

Comment: Have you checked the output of the binary? The compilers are pretty smart nowadays and will likely do wonders with it. Don't prematurely optimize unless you have proof that it is somehow a bottleneck. Plus you have an obnoxious amount of memory at your fingertips, this isn't the 1960's ;)

Comment: I have no idea what the first sentence means

Comment: If having 1 int on the stack was cause to worry, all programmers' hair would have turned white quite a while ago.  You should not worry about that.  In fact  most, if not  all programmers will encourage you to consider placing small variables on the stack as the preferred alternative,  That's the safest place to place a variable you don't want another thread to access.

Comment: You worry about local variable `int`... Whereas you pass `std::vector` by copy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i declare the variable inside the method?

Yes. Not only that, but it is the best approach.

> What i am afraid of is like every time it will declare the variable and i am afraid of wasting memory or erasing the data `idk`.

I am willing to bet that won't be a performance bottleneck. Computers are equipped to handle a lot more complexity.

> declaring it everytime and wasting memory.

The variable will be initialized every time the function call is made but it is not wasting memory. It is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only good, it is recommended. Variables should be declared in the smallest possible enclosing scope. This one will be allocated on the stack when the method is entered, and deallocated when the method exits, essentially without cost.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wasting any memory, this variable is in the stack and stops existing when the function is over. But yeah, it will be reset every time you call the function.

If you want the value to be persistent, make it a `static int`. This variable will be no longer in the stack, but will be allocated only once.

Comment: ...and that's when data race issues and trouble start.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Indeed, though he is clearly a long way from dominating multithreads.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declaring an integer (and never using it for anything) is absolutely free, since if you have optimizations enabled (which you will if you care about performance) the compiler will simply remove it from the generated binary.

Assuming that your actual code does use the integer for something, it's still almost free; it will take up four or eight additional bytes of stack space (depending on your CPU architecture) while the function is executing, but that's a trivial amount of RAM that isn't worth worrying about.  It won't take up any additional CPU cycles unless you get or set its value, and even then getting or setting the value of an integer is close enough to free that you needn't worry about it.